# Unexpected implicit cast to String: layout tag was EditText error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, androidx

I am getting this error.

Unable to solve this error please help.

there are no other errors in project.

Stuck at this.

MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String name, email;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Button submit;
    DatabaseReference rootRef,demoRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name =  findViewById(R.id.uName);
        email = findViewById(R.id.uEmail);
```

I am using constarint layout. I have set everything correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/uName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

error

```
Unexpected implicit cast to String: layout tag was EditText less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Keeps track of the view types associated with ids and if it finds a usage of the id in the Java code it ensures that it is treated as the same type.  Issue id: WrongViewCast
 Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds: View and String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow

Actually you are trying to get reference of a editText from your layout.

`name =  findViewById(R.id.uName);`

The variable `name` is not a `EditText` type variable. it is `String` type variable. thats why your app showing casting exception. 
Use `EditText` instead of `String` and Replace

```
String name, email;
```

with

```
EditText name, email;
```

Comment: Silly mistake of me :(